# Binding to TreeView and DataGrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm pretty new to WPF and I'm having a problem I cannot solve.
There's a dataset with two tables, T1 and T2. T1 has a recursive structure like this

T1Id
ParentId
Name

and this relationship:

```
ds.Relations.Add("RecursiveRel",
  tables["T1"].Columns["T1Id"],
  tables["T1"].Columns["ParentId"]);
```

I'm displaying this table in a TreeView by binding it to a DataView:

```
DvT1 = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
DvT1.RowFilter = string.Format("Id = '{0}'", IdOfFirstRecord);
```

And in XAML:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding DvT1}">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding RecursiveRel}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

This works fine and displays the hierarchy nicely in the treeview.

And now table T2 comes into play which has this structure:

T2Id
T1Id
Name

There is a 1:n relation between T1 and T2 where n >= 0. A relation has been added to the DataSet:

```
ds.Relations.Add("T1ToT2",
  tables["T1"].Columns["T1Id"],
  tables["T2"].Columns["T1Id"]);
```

T2 is using a DataGrid and it should only display records that are linked to the currently selected T1 record.
What should go into the DataGrid's ItemsSource to make this happen? I haven't found anything that would do this. 
I should also notice, if that matters, that this is a MVVM application, so code-behind is not an option.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it is the MVVM application, why do you use these strange tables and relations? It is recommended to transform all models to view models and use real properties and observable collections instead of datasets and other dynamic views.

Comment: This is how I receive the data from a remote system (non Microsoft). Why are these tables strange? Because of the recursive structure of T1?

Comment: Because of the string literals and square brackets. At first it would be better to create view models for each data model, because binding to a class like `class T1ViewModel { public ObservableCollection<T2ViewModel> T2Items { get; set; } }` is much more convenient and easier.

Comment: "this is a MVVM application, so code-behind is not an option": you should get this out of your head... MVVM doesn't mean "no code-behind". Sometimes code-behind *is* the right place to do something (although probably not in this case)

Comment: I wish I could give you an extra point for the way you asked "What dhould go into the DataGrid's ItemsSource to make this happen?" This is the only question/answer that has truly helped me with my particular TreeView/Entity Framework binding issues. Very very appreciative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.T1ToT2, ElementName=theTreeView}" />
```

Comment: Ahh, that did the trick! Merci! Yes, I know, I should not be too dogmatic about code-behind and MVVM. I'll also try vorrtex' suggestion and transform the Dataset to ObservableCollection/Properties.